# How to evaluate derivative in the form of $\log^n_nx$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

How does one evaluate this derivative?
$$\frac d{dx}\left[\sum^N_{n=2}\log^n_nx\right]$$

---

**Work so far:**

The differentiation operator and the sigma can be easily swapped but it's more of a question about a general derivative for $$\frac d{dx}\log^n_nx, \qquad\forall n\ge2.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log_n^n{x} = \left ( \frac{\log{x}}{\log{n}}\right)^n$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left ( \frac{\log{x}}{\log{n}}\right)^n = \frac{n}{\log^n{n}} \frac{\log^{n-1}{x}}{x}$$

It's basically the chain rule at work.

One way to write the derivative of the above sum is

$$\frac d{dx}\left[\sum^N_{n=2}\log^n_nx\right] = \frac{1}{x \log{x}} \sum^N_{n=2} n\log^n_nx$$